# Script bash lento

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, download, wget

Eu uso um script em bash para fazer tradução das palavras de outros idiomas para o português. Ele sempre funcionou muito bem, mas de uns dias para cá ficou extremamente lento, ao ponto de eu não conseguir usá-lo. 
algumas pessoas me informaram que o problema poderia esta no "wget". 
Eu fiz alguns testes substituindo o "wget" pelo "Axel" ou pelo "aria2c" e a velocidade voltou ao normal, porém usando esses dois comandos não consigo obter a tradução.

O código original é esse aqui:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
text="$(xsel -o)"
translate="$(wget -U "Mozilla/5.0" -qO - "http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=pt&dt=t&q=$(echo $text | sed "s/[\"'<>]//g")" | sed "s/,,,0]],,.*//g" | awk -F'"' '{print $2}')"
echo -e "Original text:" "$text"'\n' > /tmp/notitrans
echo "Translation:" "$translate" >> /tmp/notitrans
zenity --text-info --title="Translation" --filename=/tmp/notitrans
```

A linha 3 desse código, substituindo "wget" pelo "Axel" fica:

```
translate="$(axel -n 4 "http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=pt&dt=t&q=$(echo $text | sed "s/[\"'<>]//g")" | sed "s/,,,0]],,.*//g" | awk -F'"' '{print $2}')"
```

E substituindo o "wget" por "aria2c", fica:

```
translate="$(aria2c "http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=pt&dt=t&q=$(echo $text | sed "s/[\"'<>]//g")" | sed "s/,,,0]],,.*//g" | awk -F'"' '{print $2}')"
```

Possivelmente eu não estou sabendo setar as opções para o Axel e aria2c. 
Para mim tanto faz qualquer um deles, eu preciso que o código funcione de novo. Alguém saberia me orientar nesse sentido?

Comment: Ja existe uma ferramenta que ja faz isso, de uma olhada: https://github.com/soimort/translate-shell

Comment: Gfleck, essa ferramenta é apenas para uso no terminal. O script que eu uso é mais livre, posso usá-lo em qualquer ambiente e, por isto, é mais prático. Como leio livros longos, é mais rápido ter um script que reconhece palavras destacadas e mostra a definição automaticamente; isso agiliza muito a leitura.

Answer (score 1):

Parece improvável que o atraso seja devido ao wget. (mas não é esta a questão)

Provavelmente o problema com os exemplos testados tem a ver com a falta de definição
de User-agent (o -U "Mozilla/5.0" do wget) -- que faz com que o googleapis não aceite o pedido.

Sugestão usar o `curl`.

```
$ gapi="http://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=auto&tl=pt&dt=t"
$ curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" $gapi -d 'q=le fromage est trés bon'
[[["o queijo é muito bom","le fromage est trés bon",null,null,3.....["fr"]]]
```

Processando a resposta do web-service (`respostaJSON[0][0][0]`):

```
$ curl -A "Mozilla/5.0" $gapi -d 'q=le fromage est trés bon'| jq .[0][0][0]
"o queijo é muito bom"
```

Comment: JJoão, parece que o problema era a porta Ipv6, de alguma forma ela não estava deixando o wget fazer sua conexão com o Google. Eu configurei o wget para usar a porta Ipv4, adicionando o "-4" logo após ele, (wget -4 "Mozilla/5.0" ...) e o script voltou ao normal.

Comment: @Ricardo, por vezes, alguns destes webservices têm alguns limites máximos de consultas, ao fim dos quais cortam ou retardam as respostas